# Is it possible to limit the total number of database connections in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ado.net, npgsql

I have an API server that interacts with an Azure-hosted PostgreSQL database instance. There are a large number (>50) of postgres databases on that one postgres server. Any given API request may have to interact with any given database.

Unfortunately, our Azure plan for Postgres only allows 50 connections. I regularly have requests fail because Postgres won't accept more. My ADO.NET connection pool is still holding onto database connections for recently used databases, while connections to other databases error out.

I've tried setting the `Max Pool Size` on my connection strings, but it appears that the connection pool limit is applied *per database*, not *per server*. I still need as much pooling as I can get, opening new connections can take >1500ms, which is beyond my SLA if it happens on every request.

Is there a way to ask .NET to never open more than 50 database connections, either per server or total?

Comment: ***"My ADO.NET connection pool is still holding onto database connections for recently used databases"*** Maybe disposing of the objects is needed?

Comment: I'm properly disposing all of the connection objects (with `using` blocks). My understanding is that the connection pool will intentionally keep the connection open so that it can be reused for a later query. Correct me if this sounds wrong to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Max Pool Size` and instead of connecting to a separate database connect to the same database on the server and then execute the `\connect` statement to change to the desired database. The following code fragment demonstrates creating an initial connection to the `master` database and then switching to the desired database specified in the `databaseName` string variable.

```
// Assumes that command is a NpgsqlCommand object and that  
// connectionString connects to master.  
command.Text = "\connect DatabaseName";  
using (NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(  
  connectionString))  
  {  
    connection.Open();  
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();  
  }
```